# Java: How to PROPERLY access methods from another class | Example code inside

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I'm wondering what is the best/correct way to access methods from other classes in java.

I'll show how I'm doing it right now.

Sometimes like this:

```java
public class DriverManager {

    private final SeleniumDriverManager seleniumDriverManager;

    public DriverManager() {
        this.seleniumDriverManager = new SeleniumDriverManager();
    }

    public void startDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.startWebDriver();
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver();
    }
}
```

and sometime like this

```java
public class DriverManager {

    private final SeleniumDriverManager seleniumDriverManager = new SeleniumDriverManager()

    public void startDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.startWebDriver();
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver();
    }
}
```

It's working in both cases, but is there any difference? Should I follow 1st or 2nd approach

Comment: The Java compiler translates both ways into the exactly same byte code (with the exception of the line number attribute for the `new SeleniumDriverManager()` code). So this boils down to a choice of preference.

Comment: As has already been said - there's really no difference in this case.  Personally, I'd go with your second example (no explicit constructor needed).

Comment: Personally, I'd go with your first example, because it's easier for a person to read and clearly makes a distinction between static fields and class fields.  As @Thomas Kläger said, it's a choice of personal preference or shop coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.
In the first one, `seleniumDriverManager` is initialized directly in the constructor via `this.seleniumDriverManager = new SeleniumDriverManager();`.
In the second one, `seleniumDriverManager` is initialized when the (generated) default no-arg constructor is called (similar to what happens in the first case).

Nevertheless, the best approach could be different:

```java
public class DriverManager {

    private final SeleniumDriverManager seleniumDriverManager;

    public DriverManager(SeleniumDriverManager seleniumDriverManager) {
        this.seleniumDriverManager = seleniumDriverManager;
    }

    public void startDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.startWebDriver();
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        seleniumDriverManager.quitWebDriver();
    }
}
```

In this case, you actually request the `seleniumDriverManager` to be passed in the constructor as an argument. This is one of the bases of Dependency Injection which relies on this approach of "asking" instead of (silently) providing. Dependency injection is actually the foundation of Frameworks such as Spring and has a huge amount of advantages. Still, this really depends on our use case, but keep this option in mind ;)

Comment: That's a *TERRIBLE* approach.  The caller shouldn't know or care whether the "driver" happens to be a "SeleniumDriverManager" or "something else".  And the caller *CERTAINLY* shouldn't have to explicitly create an instance of "SeleniumDriverManager" - which is what you're forcing it to do.  The *less* the caller knows, the better.  And remember: you typically need a [DI container](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/what-is-ioc-container-or-di-container) (like Spring) in order to do DI

Comment: That is why I wrote, "this really depends on our use case". No approach is a one-size-fits-all approach but it is good to know that other possibilities exist keeping them in mind. Just this.

Comment: If the OP wishes to consider DI, this might be a helpful tutorial: https://www.kloia.com/blog/implementing-dependency-injection-with-java-selenium-cucumber.  But the OP needs to be using a DI framework in the first place.

Comment: This approach given here does have it's place, but it isn't what the OP asked for. Personally I sometimes create *additional* constructors that accept parameters so that at test time I can inject mock objects